# Magento 1.9.2.4 Add Cart To Header

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, css, xml, header

I need to add a cart to the header. I am creating my own custom theme which feeds of the RWD theme. I need a cart that shows total items and value.

Comment: Please put what where you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be much faster and secure to use ready made solution like [this one](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/header-mini-cart.html).

Comment: why use extension? RWD theme have minicart as default :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to the custom-theme/default/layout/local.xml file.

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="top-cart" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I then added the following code to the custom-theme/default/page/html/header.phtml where I wanted the cart to show.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('top-cart'); ?>
```

I then customised the style and layout of the following page.

custom-theme/default/template/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml